# VBA Loop through Column for Positive/Negative Numbers

Tags: vba, loops

I am new to VBA (as in I basically don't know anything about how to code in VBA, but I know python and general coding logic). I have an excel spreadsheet with a particular stock's data from 2004-2014 for every day the NYSE has been open. This data includes about 20 columns, but there are only 3 that I care about: the date (col a), a column with a specific percentage (col h), and a column with the price (col k). I want to write a simple program such that:

1) locate first positive percentage from column h, and the values in the same row for column a and k (i.e., if it's the third row, then find values from cells A3, H3, and K3)

2) locate the first negative percentage following the first positive percentage from step 1 in the same column h, and its corresponding values from column a and k (i.e., if it's the 7th row, then find values from cells A7, H7, and K7)

3) find the % difference of the 2 values found in the k column from the above two steps, and the difference in the number of rows from the positive and the negative percentage (i.e. 7-3=4)

4) Do this for the entire set of data which has almost 3000 rows of data - for example, after completing steps 1, 2, and 3, the program should find the first positive percentage following the negative percentage in step 2, then find the first negative percentage after that, and then find the % difference of the values in the k column and the difference in the number of rows

5) Place the information from the first 4 steps into a new spreadsheet (the values in the A, H, and K columns, the % differences, and the difference in the number of rows from the positive percentage and the negative percentage)

Can someone please write the VBA code for me for this, as I am new to VBA but need to get this done by tomorrow! Also, any tips on how to get started learning VBA would be very much appreciated! Thanks in advance, and Happy New Year!

Please let me know if you need anything clarified.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

```
Sub CompareData()
Dim srcwsh as Worksheet, dstwsh as Worksheet
Dim i as Integer, j as Integer
'source worksheet
Set srcWsh = Thisworkbook.Worksheets(1) ' or Thisworkbook.Worksheets("SheetName")
'destination worksheet
Set dstWsh = Thisworkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=Thisworkbook.Worksheets(Thisworkbook.Worksheets.Count))
'define headers
dstWsh.Range("A1") = "Date"
dstWsh.Range("B1") = "Percentage"
dstWsh.Range("C1") = "Price"
dstWsh.Range("C1") = "Difference"    
'start searching from 2. row
i = 2
Do While srcwsh.Range("A" & i)<> ""
    'if value of column H is positive
    If srcwsh.Range("H" & i)>0 Then
        'find first empty row in a destination worksheet
        j = GetFirstEmptyRow(dstWsh)
        Union(srcWsh.Range("A" & i), srcWsh.Range("H" & i), srcWsh.Range("K" & i)).Copy dstWsh.Range("A" & j)
        dstWsh.Range("D" & j).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(D" & j-1 & "-D" & j & "),'',D" & j-1 & "-D" & j & ")"
    End If
    i = i+1
Loop

End Sub

Function GetFirstEmptyRow(ByVal wsh as Worksheet, ByVal Optional sCol As String = "A") As Integer
    GetFirstEmptyRow = wsh.Range(sCol & wsh.Rows.Count).End(xlShiftUp).Row +1
End Function
```

Note: above code hasn't been tested!

All you need to do is to change the code to your needs. Good luck!